# Identifying Variant Conservation Across Species

Tags: blast, ensembl

I've got gene sequences of mouse genes. Each sequence contains variants from the reference genome. I need to find out whether these SNPs/variations are in functionally significant regions (i.e. exons).

I also need to see if these SNPs/mutations are conserved across species.

I'm not very proficient in this, but would BLAST or ENSEMBL be useful here? Is there an easy way to search this? I have the sequences as .txt files. I'm proficient in Python if that's useful as well.

Comment: search for variant annotation tools. I can think of VEP in Ensembl, SnpEff, .. You would need your variants in VCF format (possibly other formats) and the tools annotate each variant with various qualitative/quantitative metrics you require

Comment: VEP online: https://www.ensembl.org/Tools/VEP